# window.event.srcelement not working in firefox

Tags: javascript

```
 _eventButtonElement = window.event.srcElement;
```

How can I solve that in firefox?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firefox uses an event argument that gets passed into an event function

Change your code from this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    //CODE
    _eventButtonElement = window.event.srcElement;
    //CODE
};
```

To this:

```
window.onload = function(e) {
    //CODE
    _eventButtonElement = window.event.srcElement || e.target;
    //CODE
};
```

Comment: Kinda hard without the original code, right? :P ; I usually use `var e = window.event||e;`

Comment: yeah but since all he wants is the target it seems pointless to normalize e then nomalize again with _eventButtonElement=e.srcElement||e.target

Answer (score 5):

One of the cross Browser issues. Use this:

```
var evnt = event || window.event;
_eventButtonElement  = evnt.target || evnt.srcElement;
```

Comment: It is not work because it is called event method to not going next statement.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:
_eventButtonElement = window.event.srcElement || window.event.originalTarget;

originalTarget is the firefox equivalent to srcElement.